# yii2 twig: this.render и this.beginBlock или twig block и include — есть ли разница?

Tags: yii2, twig

Есть ли разница — использовать нативные twig-функции для блоков и включения других представлений или вызывать yii-шные класса `View this.render` и `this.beginBlock/endBlock`?

```
{% include 'subtemplate.twig '%}
{% block pagedata %}
{% endblock %}
```

а можно yii - методами

`

```
{{ this.render('subtemplate.twig') |raw }}

{{ void(this.beginBlock('pagedata')) }}
{{ void(this.endBlock()) }}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что применение шаблонизаторов зависит исключительно от команды разработчиков. Не все могут работают с шаблонизаторами, что порождает трудности при разработки. А так дело как бы ваше. Разницы сильной нет. В случае с Twig никакой бесполезной траты ресурсов нету — шаблон транслируется в тот же самый РНР код.Шаблоны нужны для разделения бизнес-логики и логики отображения. 

Пример №1: один и тот же core установлен на разных сайтах. Если используется шаблонизация, то обновление движка сводится к простой заливке кода. Если шаблонизация не используется, то под каждый сайт core надо редактировать отдельно. 

Пример №2: одно и то же приложение может возвращать как HTML, так и JSON. Если для первого использовался шаблонизатор, то добавить второе можно не трогая код. В противном случае код придется переписывать (и дублировать).

Также накопал пример Native vs Twig (Yii2):

**Native Yii2**

```
<? echo $user->percent?$user->percent:0; ?> 
<? echo $user->getTotalLikes(); ?>
<? if ($user->countComments > 0): ?>
<? $this->renderPartial('//user/_comments', array('comments'=>$user->comments)); ?>
<? else: ?>
<div style="padding-left: 35px;"><? echo Yii::t('user', 'Вы не добавляли комментариев к постам'); ?>.</div>
<? endif; ?>
<p><? if (!empty($ct['parent']->image)): ?><img src="<?php echo $ct['parent']->getImageUrl('small'); ?>"><? endif; ?>
<? echo Yii::app()->createUrl('user/register', array('ref'=>$user->id)); ?>
```

**Twig Yii2**

```
{{ user.percent|default(0) }}
{{ user.getTotalLikes() }}
{% if user.countComments %}
{% include "views/user/_comments.twig" %}
{% else %}
<div style="padding-left: 35px;">{{ Yii.t('user', 'Вы не добавляли комментариев к постам') }}.</div>
{% endif %}
<p>{% if comment.getImageUrl %}<img src="{{ comment.getImageUrl('small') }}">{% endif %}
/user/register?ref={{ user.id }}
```

P.S. Также можете приглянуться к Smarty. Выбор индивидуален для каждого. Удачного кодинга...

Comment: Спасибо, не не совсем то что хотелось бы услышать. Использование twig - это уже решенный вопрос. 
Просто в твиге можно инклудить и использовать блоки в нативной твиг-манере 
```
{% include 'subtemplate.twig '%}
{% block pagedata %}
{% endblock %}
```
а можно yii - методами
```
{{ this.render('subtemplate.twig') |raw }}

{{ void(this.beginBlock('pagedata')) }}
{{ void(this.endBlock()) }}
```